# C2DM registration returning "null" to device

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Occasionally devices receive "null" or "" from Google for C2DM registration in place of the ID. As these are remote devices, I can not simply ask the user to try again.

Is there any known reason why this would be happening, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Could it be, that these devices don't have the Android Market App installed? Or is your app distributed via the market so you can exclude this?

Comment: While that could be a possibility, I have seen it happen on my device, which I know has the market.

In other news: I just found out that the device in question was NOT set up yet, so if you answer the question as a possible solution I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

This may also happen when a device (or rather your code) requests C2DM token too often. Google considers that as robot generated requests and sends captcha challenge instead of the token.

I have a test android device (which I use to test my code on) that can no longer register for C2DM messages as it does not receive the registration token because it has too many C2DM token request on its account.

Question here is probably how to un-ban these devices?